# How to parse a wikipedia page in Python?

Tags: python

I've been trying to parse a wikipedia page in Python and have been quite successful using the API.

But, somehow the API documentation seems a bit too skeletal for me to get all the data. 
As of now, I'm doing a requests.get() call to

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&titles=China&format=json&exintro=1
```

But, this only returns me the first paragraph. Not the entire page. I've tried to use allpages and search but to no avail. A better explanation of how to get the data from a wiki page would be of real help. All the data and not just the introduction as returned by the previous query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be using the query action to get the content of the page. According to it's api specs it returns only a part of the data. The proper action seems to be query.

Here is a sample

```
import urllib2
req = urllib2.urlopen("http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&page=China&format=json&prop=text")
content = req.read()
# content in json - use json or simplejson to get relevant sections.
```

Comment: I noticed a spelling mistake, its `urllib` not `urlib` I fixed in my edit

Comment: Thanks @JakobBowyer Did not realize it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to extract the content from the page?

While I haven't used this for wikipedia, others have, and having used it to scrape other pages and it is an excellent tool.

Comment: Won't scraping take more time than using the API?

Answer (score 0):

If someone is lookin for a python3 answer here you go:

```
import urllib.request
    req = urllib.request.urlopen("http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&page=China&format=json&prop=text")
    print(req.read())
```

I'm using python version 3.7.0b4.